# CSV to Xls conversion using Pandas script

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying to convert csv to xls using Python script. I have a sample csv file - test_report.csv and it is having the below values

```
COL1  COL2   COL3
A      1      
B      2     
C      5
```

COL3 is having empty or NULL values.

When I am trying to convert csv to xls using python script, I'm not able to see COL3 in the converted file HEADER as it is not having any data. If data is there is COL3, I can see the HEADER part and the corresponding values without any issue.

I have tried the below script. Not sure what mistake I'm making.

```
import os
os.chdir("/dev/test/test01/sub/subdir01/")

# Reading the csv file

import pandas as pd
print(pd.__file__)
col_names=["COL1","COL2","COL3"]


df_new  = pd.read_csv("test_report.csv", quotechar='"', names=col_names, sep="|",skiprows=1, low_memory=False,error_bad_lines=False,header=None).dropna(axis=1, how="all")

# Saving xlsx file

file = f"test_report{pd.Timestamp('now').strftime('%Y%m%d_%I%M')}.xlsx"
df_new.to_excel(file, index=False)
```

Need guidance on fixing this issue.

Comment: It works fine for me. I see COL3. What is your version of Pandas? Do you know if you use openpyxl or xlsxwriter?

Comment: you have `.dropna(axis=1, how="all")` while reading the .csv to new_df...
it deletes empty column

Comment: I am using Pandas 3.9.9